# About upper asymptotic density.

Tags: probability, combinatorics, density-function

Let $A$ be a subset of $\mathbb{N}$ and $(p_i)_i$ a strictly increasing sequence of positive integers. We define

$\overline{d}(A|(p_i)_i):=\limsup_n \frac{\left| A \cap \left\{ p_1,\cdots , p_n \right\} \right|}{n} $.

My question is: Let $A \subset \mathbb{N}$ and $(p_i)_i$, $(q_i)_i$ strictly increasing sequence of positive integers. If $\overline{d}(A|(p_i)_i)=1$ and $\overline{d}(\bigcup_{i \in \mathbb{N}}^{}\left\{ q_i \right\}|(p_i)_i)=1$, then we have $\overline{d}(A|(q_i)_i)=1$ ?

I couldn't prove it, Is there a counterexample?

Comment: Any such sequence $(p_i)_i$ satisfies $\bar{d}(\mathbb{N}|(p_i)_i) = 1$. Can you see why?

Comment: @Michh  I had written it wrong. I edited.

Answer (score 0):

Definitely not in general. Take $A$ to be a set whose density (the usual density in the integers) equals $\alpha$; take the $p_i$ to be precisely the elements of $A$, so that $\overline d(A|(p_i))=1$; and take $q_i=i$ for all $i$, so that $\overline d(\{q_1,q_2,\dots\}|(p_i))=1$. Then $\overline d(A|(q_i))=\alpha$, which can be any number in $[0,1]$.

Comment: And if I add to the hypothesis that desity of A is 1 ?

Comment: Still no: let $A$ be the composites, $p_i$ be the successor of the $i$th prime, and $(q_i)$ the sequence of primes together with their successors. (By the successor of $n$ I just mean $n+1$.) I think one can modify this to get $0$ as the last density and not just $\frac12$.

Comment: The assertion is claiming: if most $p$s are in $A$ and most $p$s are $q$s, then most $q$s are in $A$. There's really no reason to think this is true when there are a lot more $q$s then $p$s.